# How to better organize multi-views in a web single page app?

Tags: javascript, html, web, navigation

Assume I have a lot of *views* in my single page app. It means, I put some *view* inside a div and show this or that view depending on user's actions. So, I usually show on view at a time. For example, I have these views - **dashboard**, **settings**, **entries**, **entry details**.

Depending on current state of the app one of these views is visible and others aren't. When I go this way **dashboard** > **entries** > **entry details**, then edit some entry details and click *save* or *back* button, I want the app to go back to **entries**. But if I have a link on dashboard that, for example goes to the latest edited entry, I can go this way **dashboard** > **entry details**, and in this case I want to get back to the dashboard by clicking *save* or *back* button.

This case can become even more complex with deeper *views* paths. Right now I manage it like this - When a button responsible for views switching is clicked, the variable `state` is being changed to something like `from_dashboard_to_entries`. I listen for that variable to change, then do all the view switching from another function depending on the `state` variable value. This way I have to manually define all possible scenarios and test all the possible combinations of cases. Right now this approach works quite well, but I am worried about deeper, or longer views sequences.

My idea is to somehow create a history of views in an array or something but I am not clearly understand how to do it better.
Please share your thoughts how you would organize this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't worry about the source view - you don't have to know it to change to the destination view. If you want a history, instead of manually storing it, consider using the [HTML5 History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html), preferably with a wrapper library (e.g. [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)).

Answer (score -2):

Rather, We should be setting the view while changing the state of application. This may optimize the initial app launch time by not loading all the views at launch and will give a way for on-demand loading.